# How can an XML node be its own child node?

Tags: xml, excel, vba

I have the following structure for my XML file and I am using the MSXML2 v6.0 library in VBA (Excel 2013).

```
<root>
    <products> 
        <product>relational database</product>
        <product>virtual machine</product>
    </products>
</root>
```

When I examine the `product` node, it says that the value is "relational database" (for the first node), but it also lists the childNode as "relational database".  How is this possible?

I was hoping to be able to figure out programmatically whether or not I have reached the bottom of the node tree by seeing if there are more child nodes, but it seems that this is not possible if it's always self-referencing the current node as its own child (I noticed this only happens when the node has text in it.  If it just has an attribute but no text, it shows childNodes as being empty).

Any ideas for why a node will count itself as its own child node when there is text for that node, but no actual sub-elements, as well as any way to actually determine when I've reached the end of the node tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the XML DOM, the text contained in an element is also a child node internally named `#text`

The reason for this is that some elements can contain a mix of text an other elements like:

```
<p> Hello <strong>Wonderful</strong> World</p>
```

In this case every text (`Hello` and  `World`) becomes a child `#text` node.

Comment: Is there any way to just get the text of the node, without actual child nodes being included in the text?

Comment: To get the text of the node use the Text property. To get only child nodes different from text nodes, use selectNodes( '*' ) and you'll get a list similar to childNodes